# QR Code to Google Sheets in Andriod Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have many QR codes ex. [Example on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiveA.jpg), which has peoples' names, numbers, and emails, and I need to scan them. The data comes in something like this: "joe,1234567890,joe@joe.com". I want to write an app that uploads the data to a google sheet and I found a tutorial online from [crazycodersclub.com](https://www.crazycodersclub.com/android/scan-qrcode-and-save-it-in-google-sheet-using-google-app-scriptpreviously-i-have-posted-about-insert-and-fetching-data-from-google-sheet-to-android-app-so-here-i-am-covering-complete-crud-operation-i/), but when I do the same thing it gives me an error, something like:

```
Exception: Invalid argument: URL (line 11, file &quot;Code&quot;)
```

**Google Script Code**

```js
function doGet(e){

  var url = encodeUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IEAHcv2n33YO9d7IbfWNVLv2Hl1Q1UXveazPcgMZrMs/edit?usp=sharing/")
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 return insert(e,sheet);
}

function doPost(e){
  var url = encodeUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IEAHcv2n33YO9d7IbfWNVLv2Hl1Q1UXveazPcgMZrMs/edit?usp=sharing/")
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IEAHcv2n33YO9d7IbfWNVLv2Hl1Q1UXveazPcgMZrMs/edit?usp=sharing/");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  return insert(e,sheet);
}

function insert(e,sheet) {

  var scannedData = e.parameter.sdata;
  var d = new Date();
  var ctime =  d.toLocaleString();
  
  sheet.appendRow([scannedData,ctime]);
  
  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput("Success")
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);  
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.tarbiya.scannerapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String scannedData;


    Button scanBtn;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Activity activity =this;
        scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);

        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if(result!=null) {
            scannedData = result.getContents();
            if (scannedData != null) {
                // Here we need to handle scanned data...
                new SendRequest().execute();


            }else {
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



    public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        protected void onPreExecute(){}

        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try{

                //Enter script URL Here
                URL url = new URL("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby_G_K-kmm77peQBSY6xmNZjsDcFIkDgqZwxz6e7guyte5Lxe8/exec");

                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();

                //int i;
                //for(i=1;i<=70;i++)


                //    String usn = Integer.toString(i);

                //Passing scanned code as parameter

                postDataParams.put("sdata",scannedData);


                Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line="";

                    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return sb.toString();

                }
                else {
                    return new String("false : "+responseCode);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

        while(itr.hasNext()){

            String key= itr.next();
            Object value = params.get(key);

            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

If you need to see more code, I can attach some more. It looks basically the same as the one in the tutorial right now.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about line 11 of `Exception: Invalid argument: URL (line 11, file &quot;Code&quot;)`, for `doGet` and `doPost`, when `###` of `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(###)` is modified to `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IEAHcv2n33YO9d7IbfWNVLv2Hl1Q1UXveazPcgMZrMs/edit`, what result will you obtain? By the way, when you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you were receiving the `Exception: Invalid argument: URL` message is because the `url` you were passing to the `openByUrl` was not in the correct format.

If you check the documentation for the `openByUrl` method [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl), you can see the accepted format of the link.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit
```

In your situation, you will have to remove the part after the `/edit`.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script SpreadsheetApp Class - openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl).

Comment: Thanks for the link, very helpful!